# how to foreach data from same database with two tables laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach

I have written a code to view data but I'm having some problems.

From the code, I wrote it's viewing the data from one table which is the `$details`. But I also wanna view the data from the $detailsAns.

How can I do that? also, can I `foreach` two data from that two tables?

my code below:

```
public function queries($companyID, $entityType, $entityValue)
{
    $data = [];
    $details = DiraQuestion::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();
    $detailsAns = DiraResponses::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();

    foreach($details as $key => $detailsValue)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($detailsValue->intent, $data))
        {
        $data[$detailsValue->intent] = [];
        }

        if(!array_key_exists($detailsValue->reply, $data[$detailsValue->intent]))
        {
            $data[$detailsValue->intent]['answer'][$detailsValue->reply] = $detailsValue->id;
        }

        if(!array_key_exists($detailsValue->queries, $data[$detailsValue->intent]))
        {
            $data[$detailsValue->intent]['question'][$detailsValue->queries] = $detailsValue->id;
        }
    }

    ksort($data);
    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.queries', compact('data','entityType','entityValue','companyID'));
}
```

so as you can see I can return the data from `foreach` for `$details` but now I want to return data for $detailsAns also. how can I do that?

my database structure:

table1:
[image]

table2:
[image]

so to get the data it first has to select the company id, eType, eVal, and intent so from that now i need to display the reply and queries.

The output that i want is as below:
[image]

So as you can see i can output the questions table in the foreach that i did. and if i change the foreach to $detailsAns then i display the reply.. but i want to view the both now

Comment: can you include the values inside `$details` and `$detailsAns` together with your expected output

Comment: hi @Miggy please check updated question

Comment: are there any relationships to your `questions_table` and `response_table`? if there are none, i think it would be better to add one because an answer data should be connected to a question

Comment: no there shouldnt be any relationship between the two tables. i just want to view both the data in on page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't very clear from the data provided how the tables relate to each other. If the answer has the same `id` value as the question, it is easy to relate them by structuring the arrays so that they are keyed by the common value.

```
$data = [];

$details = DiraQuestion::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();
foreach ($details AS $datum) {
    if (!isset($data[$datum->intent])) $data[$datum->intent] = ['question' => [], 'answer' => []];
    $data[$datum->intent]['question'][$datum->id] = $datum->queries;
}

$detailsAns = DiraResponses::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();
foreach ($detailsAns AS $datum) {
    if (!isset($data[$datum->intent])) $data[$datum->intent] = ['question' => [], 'answer' => []];
    $data[$datum->intent]['answer'][$datum->id] = $datum->reply;
}
```

At this point, since you said that there is no relation between the data sets, just pass the `data` array to the view the way you already are:

```
return view('AltHr.Chatbot.queries', compact('data','entityType','entityValue','companyID'));
```

And loop through both elements of data, printing out values in the view:

```
@foreach ($data['approval-document']['question'] as $id=>$question)
<p>Question #{{ $id }}: {{ $question }}</p>
@endforeach

@foreach ($data['approval-document']['answer'] as $id=>$answer)
<p>Answer #{{ $id }}: {{ $answer }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: but the thing is now that the table dont need to relate to each other, i just want to view both the REPLY and QUERIES in one page. how can i do that? forget about the the ither columns eType, eVal, intent.. Just explain to me how can i view data from 2 tables in one page?

Comment: If they don't relate to each other then just use two foreach loops, one for questions and one for answers.

Comment: you mean like the first example you did?

Comment: I changed the code for just what should be relevant. I'd just build the data structures a little different than you originally did, and loop through them to print in the view. What do you think?

Comment: it works in a way but not exactly like what i want.. i mean the code that i did separates the intent but the code you did does not separate the intent it just view everything together

Comment: Sorry, I had the variable for the first array key wrong. How does it look now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163842/discussion-between-anon-and-sorak).